# Placing margins between all td except the margin-top of first td and margin-bottom of last td

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to place margins between all `<td>` except the margin-top of the `<td>` in the first row, and the margin-bottom of the `<td>` in the last row. Is that possible? Thanks.

```css
table {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 98%;
margin: 0 auto;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}
td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td> Hello World1 </td><td> Goodbye World1 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Hello World2 </td><td> Goodbye World2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Hello World3 </td><td> Goodbye World3 </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry... can you be more clear... what is the first td... do you mean td in first row

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes. Sorry. That's what I meant.

Comment: You have used border-spacing. not margin

Comment: @ketan Sorry. That's what I meant. I just didn't know how to explain what I want in terms of border-spacing. And since we can't use margins for tables, border-spacing is as close to margins as possible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing different margins on individual table cells isn't really possible. You could use `border-collapse` and `border-spacing`, but as you have noted, this applies equally to all cells in the table.

You could also use `padding` on the individual cells. So, keep the table at `border-collapse: collapse`, and use `padding` on the individual cells for spacing. This creates the visual effect of margin space, but it's not really margin.

One thing you may want to consider is wrapping your `td` content in a `div`. Then use borders – with the same color as the background – on the table cells to space them around:

```css
body { background-color: white; }

table {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
}

td {
    border-top: 10px solid white;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
    border-left: 50px solid white;
    border-right: 50px solid white;
}

tr:first-child > td { border-top:  none; }

tr:last-child > td { border-bottom:  none; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div>Hello World1</div></td>
        <td><div>Goodbye World1</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div>Hello World2</div></td>
        <td><div>Goodbye World2</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div>Hello World3</div></td>
        <td><div>Goodbye World3</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In css you have a simple solution :

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp

```
table {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 98%;
margin: 0 auto;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}
td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
  border-spacing : 0; // FIRST TD OF FIRST ROW
}
tr:nth-last-child(1) td:nth-last-child(1){
  border-spacing : 0;// LAST TD OF LAST ROW
}
```

Comment: well, it covers your problem partialy https://jsfiddle.net/ay22u1ek/ now you just find the good css for the border-spacing.